# What is the source of mantra: Om Shreem Shree Dharaya Trailokya Mohanaya namaha?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, mantras, identification-request

What is the source and all the information of this mantra:

> Om Shreem Shree Dharaya Trailokya Mohanaya namaha?

Comment: @Pandya -  Thanks , i think Vishnu TAG is more relevant  to the question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact verse is found in [Garuda Purana, Purva Khanda, Achara Kanda, Section 1, Chapter 29](https://archive.org/stream/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201#page/n103/mode/2up). These are the mantras are used in Trailokyamohini rite for the gaining of various objects and it is described by Lord Hari himself.

> हरिरुवाच
>   त्रैलोक्यमोहिनी वक्ष्ये पुरुषोत्तममुख्यकाम्। 
>   पूजामन्त्राष्ट्रीधराद्यान्धम्र्मकामादिदायकान्। १॥
>
> Hari said :-I will now describe the Trailokyamohini rite (fascinating the three worlds) of the foremost of male beings, its adoration and the mantram called Śridhara which yeilds religious profit, desire and wives.
>
> **ॐ श्रीं (श्रीः) श्रीधराय त्रैलौकयमोहनाय नमः॥** 
>   क्लीं पुरुषोत्तमाय त्रैलाक्यमोहनाय नमः॥ ३॥
>
> Srim, salutation unto the holder of Sri and the enchanter of the three worlds. Klim, salutation unto the foremost of male beings, the enchanter of the three worlds.

Comment: Triyugi Narayan Muni: Thanks you so much. I have some queries. Please tell me why shree is in bracket () and only 2 mantras are there for Trailokyamohini rite?

Comment: No not two, more are there.. You can find them in the linked page. For example this is another: Om Vishnave trailokyamohanaya namaha | Om Srim hrim klim trailokyamohanaya vishnave namaha ||  Here he just gave u the exact one u're looking for (with Sridhara in it). @SudevMuraleedharan Also, i am not sure why the Srih in brackets is there.. Mite be it's added by the translator?

Comment: Thanks Rickross, If anyone can answer why the shree is in bracket, then I can know what is the actual mantra (only this). Wrong mantra or edited by the translator can't give the desired results. Only the Real mantra has the power. I have heard from someone that this mantra helps in warding off negative effects of Shani, I am not sure if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 6):

### Source

The  Mantra you have quoted is from [**Garuda Purana**](https://archive.org/stream/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201#page/n105/mode/2up)  - **Achara Kanda - Section 1  - Chapter 30 -  Verse 8 .** " Shreedhara (vishnu) Vidhi Dharma" . But is little different.

This mantra is used in worship of Shridhara manifestation of Lord Vishnu.

> ॐ ह्रीं श्रीधराय त्रैलोक्यमोहनाय विष्णवे नमः आगच्छ ॥ .1.30.8 ॥
>
> Om Hrim Shreedharaya TrailokyaMohanaya Vishnave Namah Aagchhya
>
> Om Hrim ,Salutation unto Shreedhara , Trilokyamohana and Vishnu.

### Meaning  According to pancharatra worship of Narayana (Vishnu).

shridhar (श्रीधर)- The bearer of Śrī who listens-to-prayers”):—One of the twenty-four forms of Viṣṇu through which Nārāyaṇa manifests himself. He is accompanied by a counterpart emanation of Lakṣmī (an aspect of Devī) who goes by the name Medhā.

---

The word **Trilokya Mohana** is used as the one who attracts the three worlds
and generally used to address Narasimha  ( the man lion ) Avatar of lord Vishnu according to Narad Pancharatra.

[image]

Comment: Agachya means "come here" So it's inviting God to come into the Puja place. It looks like an Avahana Mantra.

Comment: @Rickross - Yes , you are correct. But this mantra is not a independent one i think  , but a a part of whole  pooja vidhi. And the entire  chapter is for the description of that vidhi.  Anyway i will add this line in answer as you suggested. Thanks :-)